# Avoiding Remember me security issues

Tags: authentication, remember-me

How do you avoid session hijacking and other problems with remember me on logins? One thing i know is to add a md5 or the useragent, but that's isn't a very good protection in itself... is there smthng else too?

Answer (score 2):

My general rule is: Do not incorporate such an option in an application where the user's login would be more important than the loss of their computer itself.

So... StackOverflow.com account? No biggie; if I lose my computer, that won't be among the things I'm really worrying about.

OTOH... my online banking account? No way I want anything on my computer beyond the mere presence of a bookmark to help anyone gain access to that account.

---

My opinion is that the other things are OK if you have the time/effort, but their effectiveness isn't all that great when you consider that the real, ultimate problem would be someone who has literally gained possession of their computer.

---

p.s.: *Please* consider voting this answer up/accepting it as your answer if it's useful to you

Comment: i need to have it for a social network... and for a social network, u can't say its important or not... i dont use the remember me at all, but all my friends do... so its a matter of choice

Comment: It's always important. But all security choices are always about trade-offs between security and ease-of-use. If you do enable persistent logins, just be sure you are using a reasonable method of obfuscating that info at minimum, for a social site.